# Complex derivative with respect to conjugate variable equal to the limit of a certain integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

**Problem**. If a function $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable in a neighborhood of a point $a \in \mathbb{C}$ then
$$
\lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \int_{\{|z-a|=\varepsilon\}} f(z) d z=2 \pi i \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(a) .
$$
It's an exercise on "*Introduction to complex analysis; volume 1*" by B. V. Shabat Chapter 2
and the book gives the following :

**Hint**: use the formula
$$
f(z)=f(a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a)(z-a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(a)(\bar{z}-\bar{a})+o(|z-a|)
$$ and the example
**Example**: Let $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an arbitrary piecewise smooth path and $n \neq 1$. We also assume that the path $\gamma(t)$ does not pass through the point $z=0$ in the case $n<0$. The chain rule implies that $\frac{d}{d t} \gamma^{n+1}(t)=(n+1) \gamma^n(t) \gamma^{\prime}(t)$ so that
$$
\int_\gamma z^n d z=\int_\alpha^\beta \gamma^n(t) \gamma^{\prime}(t) d t=\frac{1}{n+1}\left[\gamma^{n+1}(\beta)-\gamma^{n+1}(\alpha)\right]
$$

---

I guess maybe use $$2\pi i = \int_{\{|z-a|=\varepsilon\}} \frac{dz}{z-a}.$$ But I still don't understand ; please give more hint.

Comment: Please make the title more informative.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1133269/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2430873/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226581/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%20_%7B%5Cvarepsilon%20%5Crightarrow%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cvarepsilon%5E2%7D%20%5Cint_%7B%5C%7B%7Cz-a%7C%3D%5Cvarepsilon%5C%7D%7D%20f(z)%20d%20z%3D2%20%5Cpi%20i%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%20f%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20%5Cbar%7Bz%7D%7D(a)%20.%24)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot

Comment: The hint to write $f(z,\overline z)$ is crucial. Algebraically, a function of 2 real variables is $(z+\overline z,, i (z-\overline z) $.  $f(z)$ is independent of $\overline z$. Then, if f is independent of $\overline z$ and differentiable, the integral is 0.